# Python how do I link 2 lists?

Tags: python, list, linked-list, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have 2 lists

```
[902920,28393892,93993992,93938939929,929393993928,38982933939393, 883383938393]
```

```
[1.9, 1,7, 1,6]
```

Basically `1.9` links to `902920,28393892,93993992`
`1.7` links to `93938939929,929393993928,38982933939393`

In the for loop I need to
request.get(`1.9`, then the 3 numbers from the first list)
then `1.7` and the next 3 numbers

Anyway to make this link?

Sorry I should mention 1.6 could be linked to the next 2 numbers in the list, and another number 1.5 could be linked to the next 7.

Comment: `for n, triple in zip(firstlist, group_by_three(second_list)): request.get(n, *triple)`

Comment: Why these are in separated lists to begin with? Why not use a dict, ie `{1.9: [902920,28393892,93993992]}` ?

Comment: Do you mean `1,7` or `1.7`, etc.?

Comment: @ryandanielsim You said "[s]orry I should mention 1.6 could be linked to the next 2 numbers in the list, and another number 1.5 could be linked to the next 7." So it is not always a fixed number? In this case we would need some kind of mapping that tells us for example, if the number is `1.5`, how many elements from the other list to take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`more-itertools` has this `grouper` function that could be useful for this task. I [replicate it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) here:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
def grouper(iterable, n, *, incomplete='fill', fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into non-overlapping fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, fillvalue='x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, incomplete='strict') --> ABC DEF ValueError
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, incomplete='ignore') --> ABC DEF
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    if incomplete == 'fill':
        return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
    if incomplete == 'strict':
        return zip(*args, strict=True)
    if incomplete == 'ignore':
        return zip(*args)
    else:
        raise ValueError('Expected fill, strict, or ignore')
```

This function combined with `zip` ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)) in the way shown below returns an iterator of tuples where the first element of the tuple is an element from `b` and the second element of the tuple is a tuple of three elements taken from `a`. For this example, the iterator returned by `zip` links `1.9` to the first three elements of `a`, `1.7` to the next three elements of `a`, and so on.

```
a = [902920,28393892,93993992,93938939929,929393993928,38982933939393, 883383938393]
b = [1.9, 1.7, 1.6]

c = zip(b, grouper(a, 3))

for item in c:
    print(item)
```

**Output**

```
(1.9, (902920, 28393892, 93993992))
(1.7, (93938939929, 929393993928, 38982933939393))
(1.6, (883383938393, None, None))
```

The `grouper` function offers additional functionality. By default, where there are not enough elements left from the long `a` list to fill a 3-tuple, the empty elements will be filled with `None`. So you can set `fillvalue` to something else should you prefer to obtain a value other than `None` or you could even state that you do not want incomplete tuples as in this example

```
c = zip(b, grouper(a, 3, incomplete = 'ignore'))

for item in c:
    print(item)
```

**Output**

```
(1.9, (902920, 28393892, 93993992))
(1.7, (93938939929, 929393993928, 38982933939393))
```